# How can a non-variadic function accept different number of arguments (than with what it is defined)?

Tags: c, function

```
#include<stdio.h>

int foo();
int bar();

int main(void)
{
  foo(2,3,4);
  return 0;
}

int foo(int a, int b)
{
  return bar(a);
}

int bar(int c, int d)
{
  int e = c + d;
  printf("%d",e);
  return e;
}
```

**Output**

> 5

Why `bar()` function could receive two parameters?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.  Avoid tabs on SO.  Enter the code in the edit box as it should appear, then select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it so it appears as code.  Also note that it is best to end printing statements with a newline.  You are getting a whole lot of undefined behaviour out of your code, but the compiler can't help you because although you declared the functions `foo()` and `bar()`, you didn't specify the function prototypes.

Comment: I personally don't see any reason for downvoting this Q, this is a genuine question and many beginners face the same issue and get confused. While this can be a _silly_ question, but the question quality is good, nevertheless, atleast, it is asked in a proper manner. :-)

Answer (score 7):

A function declaration, with an *empty* parenthesis as argument list means, there is no restriction (and check) on the number and type of the arguments that the function can receive. It can be called with any number and type of arguments.

FWIW, if you want to specify a function which takes *no* arguments, you need to specify `void` as the argument list, like

```
 int foo(void);
```

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.2, *Function calls*

> ... If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
>   behavior is undefined...

So, your program  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There is absolutely no guarantee or prediction how your application will behave.

Comment: In `int bar(int c, int d)` what would be value of `c` and `d` if it is called as `bar(a)`. And would it be able to access `4` in function `foo` if I use `int foo(int a, int b)`

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish: there is no specified value for `c` or `d` when you mis-call the function.  You didn't specify function prototypes, so you forgo the the checking they provide.  You're invoking undefined behaviour; you get whatever the compiler thinks might be appropriate.  It doesn't have to tell you what that is, or be consistent about it, and it could reformat your disk drive instead of printing a semi-plausible number and you'd have no grounds for complaint — you invoked undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler and SouravGhosh I get this now.

Answer (score 6):

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.2 Function calls)

> 6. If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>      does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on
>      each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to
>      double. These are called the default argument promotions. **If the
>      number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
>      behavior is undefined.**

Thus your program has undefined behaviour.

If you specified the function prototypes before the function calls, as for example

```
//..
int foo(int a, int b);
int bar(int c, int d);

int main(void)
{
  foo(2,3,4);
  return 0;
}
//...
```

then it would be possible for the compiler to report errors and not compile and link your program.